# Is it possible to estimate prevalence from a given sample size?

Tags: prevalence

I have farms in my dataset and from each farm, I have a few animals (varies for each farm) to test for a disease. I want to know, if I tested these animals, what apparent prevalence will I be able to detect in each herd. I want to estimate this for each herd.

There is a formula for estimating the sample size for a given prevalence; but how could one estimate the prevalence, if the sample size is known?

Comment: You seem to be asking how to find the result of a sample without actually taking the sample.  Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: I have sample sizes and I want to know what is the minimum prevalence I can detect from it ( it is the reverse of sample size calculation).

Comment: What [kind of prevalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalence) are you referring to and what is the intended study design?

Comment: I have farms in my dataset and from each farm, I have few animals (varies for each farm) to test for a disease. I want to know, if I tested these animals, what apparent prevalence will I be able to detect in each herd. I want to estimate this for each herd. I hope this helps, thanks- Abby

Comment: It does help, thank you. Please include that information in your post.